# Dynamic Operator In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, operators

I have a problem.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @max int
set @max=10

declare @min int
set @min=0
Declare @oper nvarchar(40)
set @oper='>'
Declare @value int
set @value=0
declare @r_sql int
set @sql='select @r_sql = case when'+cast(@value as int)+cast(@oper as nvarchar(1))+@min+' then 1 else 0 end '

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql,
  @value,
  @min,
  @max,
  @r_sql OUTPUT
select @r_sql
```

I want to pass the dynamic operator to execute query but it always says 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.'
Anyone got this problem? Please help me. Thanks, I really appreciate.

Comment: @value is already an int, so why are you explicitly casting?

Comment: becasue when I declare var I need to be int but when I pass param to query I think that need to be string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` operator in t-sql can be a bit wonky. If you want to concatenate strings, make sure to input only strings:

```
set @sql=N'select @r_sql = case when'
          +cast(@value as nvarchar(max))
          +@oper --already a nvarchar, and the length thing is done automatically
          +cast(@min as nvarchar(max))
          +N' then 1 else 0 end '
```

Basically, what SQL Server does, is that when it sees a `+`, it's first instinct is to add two numbers.

- If things on both sides of the `+` are numbers, it will add them
- If one of the things is a number, it will try to convert the other and add them (if the conversion fails, you get the error message you posted)
- If neither of the things is a number, then and only then will SQL Server try to do string concatenation.
- (note that in SQL Server dates are just a special type of numbers)

So, in a nutshell:

```
select 1+2      => yields the number 3
select 1+'2'    => yields the number 3
select '1'+2    => yields the number 3
select '1'+'2'  => yields the string '12'

select 1+'a'    => Conversion failed error
select 'a'+2    => Conversion failed error
select 'a'+'b'  => yields the string 'ab'
```

Alternatively, if you are on SQL Server 2012 and above, you can use the `concat` function, that basically converts everything you feed it to a string, and then concatenates the strings

```
set @sql=concat(N'select @r_sql = case when', 
                @value, @oper, @min, 
                N' then 1 else 0 end ')
```